# Compiling android kernel blocked on linking of vmlinux.o

Tags: android, linux-kernel, pixel, ld, lto

I want to custom my pixel 4a kernel and following to [instruction](https://source.android.com/setup/build/building-kernels),

1. mkdir android-kernel && cd android-kernel
2. repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/manifest -b android-msm-redbull-4.19-android12
3. repo sync
4. build/build.sh

Unfortunately, while compiler trying to do link its take a long time and finally failed.
Here you can see the `https:// pastebin.com /UHurn0yA` output.
Do I missed something ?

Thanks a lot,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kernel Compiling Error in Virtualbox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1130730/kernel-compiling-error-in-virtualbox)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I create a swap file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/238783/how-can-i-create-a-swap-file)

Comment: Working ! Thanks a lot !